# javascript eval() method is degrading the performance while filtering

Tags: javascript, performance, eval

I am creating a string of where clause from an array of filters.

```
var where_clause_string = "(((true && ['SACRAMENTO','CITRUS HEIGHTS'].indexOf(raw_data[i]['city']) > -1) || (false && [].indexOf(raw_data[i]['city']) === -1)) || false)";
var raw_data_length = raw_data.length
  , filtered_data = [];
for(var i = 0; i < raw_data_length; i++) {
  if (eval(where_clause_string)) {
    filtered_data.push(raw_data[i]);
  }
}
```

Then, I am iterating over the data which is an array of objects and returning only that object which passes the truth test.

It is giving the expected result, but the performance is screwed. It takes ~2-3 seconds to filter just 1500 rows. If the condition is hardcoded without the use of eval(), the process is very fast.

What will be the alternative approach to achieve this?

Comment: eval is evil! period!

Comment: I know eval() is evil. So trying to get an alternative which fits into the this usecase.

Comment: Why don't you simply put that string directly inside of the if statement (of course, not as a string)

Comment: `What will be the alternative approach to achieve this?` - Is there a problem with hardcoding it?

Comment: Can't say any constructive, but what I've been taught: don't use eval. Even if you have to, you don't. All my teachers said there's always an alternative solution for the issue.

Comment: I cannot hardcode it (put that string directly inside of the if statement) as the string is generated on events

Comment: http://jsperf.com/how-slow-is-eval That's just it, it's slower, probably because it needs to parse an inline string, which might be slightly more complex than directly compiling it. A valid alternative could be a function, in such a case.

Comment: @RonakBhandari: you say the string is generated on events - there is likely to be a better way to pass the information needed back to the filter, could you elaborate here (or in a new question) on what the events are and the basic mechanism you have implemented?

Comment: if `true` or `false` are just variables, then i would treat them as variables. otherwise your condition allways become true, because `true && ...` is useless for a shortcut

Comment: `true` and `false` are not variables. They are the output of some other condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An alternative would be to build a function :

```
var where_clause_string = "(((true && ['SACRAMENTO','CITRUS HEIGHTS'].indexOf(raw_data[i]['city']) > -1) || (false && [].indexOf(raw_data[i]['city']) === -1)) || false)";

var evaler = new Function('raw_data', 'i', "return "+where_clause_string);

var raw_data_length = raw_data.length
  , filtered_data = [];
for(var i = 0; i < raw_data_length; i++) {
  if (evaler(raw_data, i)) {
    filtered_data.push(raw_data[i]);
  }
}
```

If you want to go further, you could use the `filter` function of `Array.prototype`. It would also ensure the function generation isn't a possible cause of deoptimization (see [Optimization Killers](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers)) :

```
var where_clause_string = "(((true && ['SACRAMENTO','CITRUS HEIGHTS'].indexOf(raw_data[i]['city']) > -1) || (false && [].indexOf(raw_data[i]['city']) === -1)) || false)";

var filtered_data = raw_data.filter(new Function(
    'v', "return "+where_clause_string.replace(/raw_data\[i\]/g,'v')
));
```

But it's usually better to start with structured data instead of a raw string you want to evaluate. Using a function as I propose gets you better performances but you still get the maintenance, readability and security problems of a code in a string. Maybe it could be something like

```
var criterium = {
    ok_cities:['SACRAMENTO','CITRUS HEIGHTS'],
    nok_cities:[]
};
```

Comment: Ok ... I've never seen such a thing (or maybe I just don't recognize it in this form). Could you provide me some link where it is explained?

Comment: @user1680977 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: @dystroy The solution worked. Can you elaborate with an example on "For better performances, it would be even better to isolate the evaler construction in another function, so that the present code can be optimized by JS engines."

Comment: @RonakBhandari It's unsure at this point and should be tested (it depends on the version of the engine). But constructs similar to `new Function` are often causes of deoptimization of the function in which they are (read https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Optimization-killers) so it's better to isolate them. As it's speculation in your precise case and as I don't have time to test right now, I'll remove the paragraph.

Comment: @dystroy The time is reduced to ~1 second. I want to further reduce it. Can you please provide a sample of scoping the evaler inside a function?

Comment: @RonakBhandari Performances should be a little better with the `filter` based solution if the array is large enough (see update)

Comment: @dystroy The filtering time on 1500 rows is ~70-100 ms. Trying to further optimize it.

Comment: I don't know the rest of the code but it's possible wrapping the filtering part in an IIFE could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var raw_data_length = raw_data.length,
    filtered_data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < raw_data_length; i++) {
    // fill all param with values some may filled above the for statement
    var param1 = true,
        param2 = ['SACRAMENTO', 'CITRUS HEIGHTS'].indexOf(raw_data[i]['city']) > -1,
        param3 = false,
        param4 = [].indexOf(raw_data[i]['city']) === -1,
        param5 = false;

    if (param1 && param2 || param3 && param4 || param5) {
        filtered_data.push(raw_data[i]);
    }
}
```